# Drag and Drop Issue Between Panel and GroupBox

Tags: vb.net

So I have a `Panel` and a `GroupBox`.  I coded it so I can drag a picture from a `Panel` to a `GroupBox` and lay it there. The problem is that I can only add 1 picture to the `GroupBox`, I want to add as many as I want and also resize the picture when I lay it in the `GroupBox` so it be smaller than it is in the `Panel`.

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    Panel1.DoDragDrop(Panel1.BackgroundImage, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub view1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles view1.DragEnter
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub view1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles view1.DragDrop
    Dim bm As Bitmap = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)

    view1.BackgroundImage = bm
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can only drop one `Inage`.  The `GroupBox` only has one `BackgroundImage` property.  What you should do is add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `GroupBox` and then, each time you drop an `Image`, add a `PictureBox` to the `FlowLayoutPanel` and load the `Image` into that.

Comment: if you don't mind can you help me with coding it please ?

Comment: The code will be very similar, except you'll need to handle dropping on the `FlowLayoutPanel` as well as or instead of the `GroupBox`.  Adding a control in code is not difficult and you can find examples of that all over the place.  Do a bit of research, give it a go and then, if it doesn't work, post what you've done and I'll be happy to help you fix it.